# Querying DBpedia from Python

Tags: python

How can I get information about an entity from DBpedia using Python?

Eg: I need to get all DBpedia information about [USA](http://dbpedia.org/page/United_States).  So I need to write the query from python (SPARQL) and need to get all attributes on USA as result.

I tried :

```
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?p ?o
WHERE { db:United_States ?p ?o }
```

But here all DBpedia information is not displaying.

How can I do this and which all are the possible plugins/api available for python to connect with DBpedia ?

Also what will be the SPARQL query for generating the above problem result?

Comment: Asking for all the plugins/API is waaay too broad for this. StackExchange is not a replacement search engine for the lazy. I could show you one way to do it, but you are asking for every possible way. Refine your question or it'll probably get closed.

Comment: Hi Spacedman, Which is the best api and bet way to get the data from DBpedia

Comment: The best API for DBpedia is the RDF download, so you can process it locally without hitting on an API at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a wrapper for DBPedia, you need a library that can issue a SPARQL query to its SPARQL endpoint.  Here is [an option for the library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SPARQLWrapper/1.6.4) and here is the URL to point it to: http://dbpedia.org/sparql

You need to issue a DESCRIBE query on the United_States resource page:

```
PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

DESCRIBE dbres:United_States
```

Please note this is a **huge** download of resulting triplets.

Here is how you would issue the query:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

def get_country_description():
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
    sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

    sparql.setQuery(query)  # the previous query as a literal string

    return sparql.query().convert()
```

Comment: Thank you logc. Yes here you are limiting attribute as 'EuropeanCountries' from all countries but what I would like to have is given a country name and then list (in json or just print) all information about that country from dbpedia.

Comment: I am aware of that, that is why I said 'a bit of work is needed'. If I have time, I will edit the answer; otherwise, consider it a starting point :)

Comment: Edited to fit the question more precisely